# SQL - convert all database table datetime type to unix int type

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database, database-migration

**What is required?**
I want to write a migration which will loop through all database tables, finds which columns are of date time type, converts that time to UNIX time and stores that UNIX time in int type column by changing that column type to int.

**What i am thinking of?**
I am thinking to achieve this by writing node.js script to get the benefit of promises and the steps will be

1. Iterate on database tables
2. For each table store the data in memory and convert date time to UNIX
3. Drop table's date time type column and add int type column with same name
4. Insert data back into table

**What i am looking for?**
I am looking for solution,suggestions or a better approach to achieve the goal with less effort. Currently code efficiency don't matter because the script runs for one time only.

Comment: just curious why you consider a migration necessary? What MySQL version may have some impact on the solution.

Comment: @danblack mysql version is 5.1.73. I also want to get back to old database state.